Limited list of words for a text or glyph-based messaging system
I'm building a world for a Pathfinder (TTRPG) mystery/political campaign, where I have a city that is a trading hub for shipping. I'm toying with the idea of having a glyph-based messaging system - magical crystals that can be used to send short messages back and forth between sets which are linked permanently when they are created.
I think it would be interesting if the crystals worked on a set of limited glyphs - e.g. maximum message length of (say) 15 glyphs, and a "word list" of (say) 50-100 glyphs, each with assigned/standard meanings. I'm coming up with all of the rules for the magic of the world so I can simply handwave the reasons for this away as "limitations of the magic".
The crystals would originally have been created to send messages between ships, so the meanings of many of the glyphs will be related to sailing, but may have been adapted/evolved over time to also mean different but related words - e.g. the glyph which was originally designated to mean "crew" may have evolved to also mean a more general group of people or an organisation such as a city guild.
I'd like for people to be able to communicate reasonably effectively, but for the messages to take some interpretation and leave some room for them to still be somewhat cryptic - as I said it's a mystery campaign, and I envisage my players finding a crystal that used to belong to somebody else, and receiving cryptic messages from an unknown sender.
As an initial idea I have the following list of words:
And
If
Then
Because
So
Not
Is/Be
Where
Want/Need
Have

Yes/Good
No/Bad

You/Your
I/Me/Us/We/My
Crew/Group/Guild/Organisation
Captain/Leader
Person

Ship
Cargo/Item
Fish

One/First
Two/Second/Return
Many/More/Big
Less/Few/Small
Last

Left/Port
Right/Starboard
North
South
East
West
Home/Harbour
Journey
Destination

Storm/Problem
Question
Danger/Warning
Calm/Solution/Answer
Send
Receive
Know/Knowledge/Information
Stop
Message
Fire
Pirates/Raiders/Enemies
Water
War
Lost/Lose
Rendezvous/Meeting

Hour
Day
Night
Week
Now
Later

Aid/Rescue
Push/Pull/Tug
Search
Go
See/Look/Eye
Sail
Emergency
Destroy/Attack

And also a character for [space].
So let's say my PCs are out in town investigating and their employer wants to message them to ask them to come back to base urgently because they have an important message, they might send:
"[Two/Second/Return] [Home/Harbour] [Now] [Emergency] [space] [I/Me/Us/We/My] [Have] [Message] [You/Your] [Want/Need] [See/Look/Eye] [Now]" - roughly translated to "Return to base urgently, I have a message you need to see now".
Hopefully this gives some idea of what I'm going for. I'd like suggestions of what I can do to make this more effective. If there are words here that I can combine (As I have with "One/First"), important or very useful words that I'm missing, etc. I'd love to hear it.
Also any suggestions for slang combinations of words that might be fun or interesting would be great. For example maybe "Go Fish" is slang for "I don't have any" or "I don't know". I suspect that sailors will have come up with many of these, and also other agreed meanings for combinations of symbols - including shorthand for specific places in the world, e.g. [East] [Fish] [Home/Harbour] might mean a specific fishing village/port on the East coast.

Greetings! So, first of all, this is giving me obvious telegrapph vibes or even textspeak vibes. R/U/CMG?  SHLD/B/TR/N/1/WK.  TNX.  If I'm right, then that could be a good avenue of research for you. Second, Stack Exchange in general really isn't a brainstorming Q&A site. So the "I'd like suggestions" approach is very likely going to get this question closed pretty quick. It looks like you've already got the system pretty well conceptualised, apart from words you're missing! I think your query has a better chance here if you edit the last two paragraphs to a more focused (cont)

(cont) question. Something like Is this a feasible form of rapid communication, given the following constraints: And then you expand a little bit on the nature of this setting. A little about the magic, a little about available technology, what you're looking for in a good answer.

Not an answer but I would include some glyphs that are proper nouns for things and empires that no longer exist, to add some authenticity.

Have you looked at diplomatic encryption codes? For instance, the famous Zimmermann Telegram of WW1, in the original telegraphed form, consisted of a string of numeric codes.

According to Grasset d'Orcet, this was exactly how European heraldry doubled as a telegraphic code: coats of arms could be read as rebuses, typically conveying military or political mots d'ordre in Picard dialect. Additionally, mottos would be in octosyllabic verses, with an "l" in the penultimate or ultimate syllable. Vowels would be mostly ignored. In his system, a chief charged with 3 fleurs-de-lys would read: Chef, Lis trois and translate to Salutaire.

why not use something like morse code or semaphore or twitter and just have a character limit. Otherwise you are trying to build an enture language from scratch.

@John Oh, you don't have to work from scratch. The nice people on the Internet have been working on this question for decades. See my answer about "toki pona". :-)

Nothing prevents you to assign letters of alphabet to the words in your word list and then communicate arbitrary messages. Only speed will be lower (and maybe price higher, if there is a cost associated with sending the messages).
Indeed, as you noted, this is pretty much the (historical) situation with the maritime flag communication - a flag by itself is a fixed message, combined with another flag is a different message, combined with numbers is yet something different, but it also stands for a letter, so you can communicate everything you want, albeit more slowly.
If speed/price is a consideration, you may want to take inspiration from our telegraph codes - whole phrasebooks covering thousands and thousands phrases were devised, some of them achieving worldwide recognition and some kind standardization. Pretty much the same would happen in your world, if there is a need and a vibrant community using the crystals (e.g. a lot of commerce).

To expand on this a bit: a dictionary of 50-100 glyphs is about 6-7 bits of information per glyph, for a total of 90-105 bits of information per message. You can fit English easily into 4 bits per character (only one case, plus some punctuation) so you've got about 25 characters worth of arbitrary text per message - you can do a lot with that, particularly if you use pidgin! And that's assuming you can't string together messages into one larger message due to speed/cost constraints. It would however likely require the use of a code book unless the reader is quite experienced.

"Nothing prevents you to assign letters of alphabet to the words in your word list and then communicate arbitrary messages" you are forgetting that any message is gibberish if not understood by the person you are talking too. If you are an English merchant trying to hail a Aramaic speaking ship, the glyphs and thier intended meaning are likely your only common language.

@Nosajimiki "your only common language" - only if the meaning assigned to the glyph is the same in the Atlantic and the Mediterranean. And if the civilization is interconnected enough to standardize the glyphs (something that happened with maritime flags quite late), there will be at least a regional a lingua franca (or even Lingua Franca) that any captain worth his salt would learn at least the basics of. Or quite likely, have some sailors speaking other widespread languages somewhat.

@RadovanGarabík Maritime flags had word meanings in the early 1300s but phonetic meanings were not first documented until the 1600s and would have only been used if the ship you are hailing is flying a flag that denotes a common language.

Allow me to introduce you to “toki pona”, a complete language in 137 words. Yes, you read that right — 137 words to be expressive as any human language. It was designed to be a basic lang for two people who didn’t speak a common language to get up to speed quickly, but it has spawned a whole community working in the language. There are thousands of speakers worldwide, showing that it is a viable complete language.
https://tokipona.org/
If you’re looking for minimal symbols with maximum expressiveness, this is it. It’s secret is vagueness followed by refinement.
Here is wordlist: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Toki_Pona_words
I am copying the complete wordlist into the answer to make it a complete answer. Words marked with * are dialects that may not be known to typical toki pona speaker. This is the complete list of words from the Wikipedia entry. This list has 159 words -- more than the core word list -- because it includes some dialect words that are not universal among speakers.
 a - interjection
 akesi - lizard or reptile
 ala - no, not, zero
 alasa - hunt
 ale - all, 100
 ali - alternate spelling of "ale" 
 anpa - down, lowly
 ante - different, other
 anu - or
 apeja - (uncommon) shame, guilt
 awen - enduring, wait, continue
 e - direct object [en] marker
 en - and (only used between multiple subjects)
 epiku - (humorous) epic
 esun - market, trade
 ijo - thing, object, matter
 ike - bad, superfluous
 iki - (archaic, obscure) he, she, it, they[source?]
 ilo - tool, device
 insa - inside, stomach
 jaki - dirty, disgusting
 jalan - (uncommon) walk
 jan - person, human
 jasima - (uncommon) reflection, mirror
 jelo - yellow, light green
 jo - have, hold
 kala - fish, sea creature
 kalama - sound, noise, recite
 kama - come, become
 kan - (archaic, obscure) with, together
 kapa - (archaic, obscure) bump, hill[source?]
 kapesi - (rare) brown, grey
 kasi - plant
 ken - can, possible
 kepeken - using
 kijetesantakalu - raccoon
 kili - fruit, vegetable
 kin - also, too
 kipisi - cut, divide, part
 kiwen - hard, solid, stone
 ko - paste, powder
 kokosila - (uncommon, humorous) speak another language when Toki Pona would be more appropriate
 kon - air, spirit
 ku - relating to Toki Pona Dictionary
 kule - color, painted
 kulupu - group, community
 kute - ear, hear, listen, obey
 la - (context phrase marker)
 lanpan - grab, seize, steal
 lape - sleep, rest
 laso - blue, green
 lawa - head, mind, control, lead
 leko - block, square
 len - cloth, clothing, cover, privacy
 lete - cold, cool, raw
 li - (predicate marker)
 lili - small, little, young
 linja - line, string, hair
 lipu - flat object, paper, document
 loje - red
 lon - at, in, on, real, true, exist
 luka - hand, arm, five
 lukin - eye, see, look at, try
 lupa - hole, door, orifice, window
 ma - land, earth, country
 majuna - (uncommon) old, ancient
 majuna in sitelen pona - 
 mama - parent, ancestor, creator, caretaker
 mani - money, wealth, cattle
 meli - woman, female, feminine, wife
 meso - average, medium
 mi - I, me, we, us
 mije - man, male, masculine, husband
 misikeke - medicine, cure
 moku - eat, consume, food
 moli - dead, die, death, kill
 monsi - back, rear
 monsuta - monster, fear, danger, scary
 mu - animal onomotopeia [en] (moo, meow, etc.)
 mun - moon, night sky object
 musi - fun, playing, game, recreation, art, entertainment
 mute - many, very, much, several, a lot, abundant, numerous, more
 n - um, hmm
 namako - extra, additional, spice, season, embellish
 namako in sitelen pona - 
 namako in sitelen pona - 
 nanpa - number, ordinal indicator [en]
 nasa - strange, silly, drunk, (nonstandard, proscribed) foolish, crazy
 nasin - way, manner, custom, road, path, doctrine, system, method
 nena - bump, hill, mountain, button, nose
 ni - this, that
 nimi - word, name
 noka - leg, foot, organ of locomotion; base
 o - O! (vocative or imperative)
 oko - eye
 olin - love, respect
 ona - he, she, it, they
 open - open, begin
 pakala - blunder, accident, mistake, destruction, damage, break
 pake - (uncommon) stop, cease
 pali - make, activity, work, deed, project
 palisa - long hard object (e.g. rod, stick, branch)
 pan - grain, cereal; bread, pasta
 pana - give, put, send, place, release, emit
 pasila - (archaic, obscure) easy[source?]
 pata - (archaic, obscure) sibling
 peta - (archaic, obscure) green[7][8]
 pi - (modifier phrase marker)
 pilin - feelings, emotion, heart
 pimeja - black, dark, shadow
 pini - end, finish, stop, past
 pipi - bug, insect
 po - (archaic, obscure) four
 poka - side, hip, next to, vicinity
 poki - container, box, bowl
 pona - good, simple, useful
 powe - (uncommon) false, fake, deceptive
 pu - relating to Toki Pona: The Language of Good
 sama - same, similar, equal, like
 seli - fire, warmth, heat
 selo - outside, surface, skin, boundary
 seme - what, which
 sewi - high, up, above, sacred
 sewi in sitelen pona - 
 sijelo - body, physical state, torso
 sike - circle, wheel, ball, year
 san - (archaic, unofficial) three, especially in senary base
 sin - new, fresh, another
 sina - you
 sinpin - front, wall, chest, face
 sitelen - picture, image, write, draw
 soko - mushroom, fungus
 sona - know, information, wisdom
 soweli - animal, (especially) land mammal
 suli - big, tall, long, important, adult
 suno - sun, light
 supa - horizontal supporting surface, platform, furniture, table, chair
 suwi - sweet, cute, sugar
 tan - from, because of, cause
 taso - but, only
 tawa - to, for, move, go
 telo - water, liquid, wet, wash, beverage
 tenpo - time, moment, period, situation
 toki - say, speech, language
 tomo - house, building, room
 tonsi - non-binary, transgender
 tu - two, halve
 tuli - (archaic, obscure) three
 unpa - sex, sexual
 unu - (rare) purple
 uta - mouth, lips, jaw, oral
 utala - conflict, battle, fight, compete
 walo - white, light-colored
 wan - one, unique, unite
 waso - bird, winged animal
 wawa - strong, power, energy
 weka - away, absent, missing
 wile - want, need, desire, must


Excellent! I felt like this must be something somebody had tried to do/started working on already. I probably won't use this word list but it's great as a reference/for inspiration.

tokipona really needs a decimal numbering system to be useful for transmititing messages, you cannot easily transmit anything navigationally/logistically useful without eating a lot of characters. 5 glyphs to transmit the number 18 is pretty bad if you are trying to reduce the number of glyphs sent

@John There exist definite weaknesses in the language, but as a starting point for general expressability, it serves remarkably well. Tailoring it to specific domains is valuable.

I agree its a good place to start but identifying where it does not work will help make what the OP needs.

Frame challenge.
As Radovan Garabík noted, "Nothing prevents you to assign letters of alphabet to the words in your word list and then communicate arbitrary messages.". If you want for the messages to be short and somewhat cryptic, I suggest going from different angle. You can write anything you want, but this way of communication is prone to be intercepted by eavesdroppers. Meaning you have to make your message short and with cryptic wording, hoping that you included just enough information and clarity that its addressees would be able to understand its meaning, while leaving potential eavesdroppers confused. Cryptography has not been invented yet 
P.S. Advanced cryptography hasn't been invented yet. Whatever methods of cryptography are available are easily cracked by professionals.
P.P.S.

ability for a civilization to think of better ways to encrypt things is directly proportional to their creativity in cracking them.

In the long run that is true, but there can be period when the sword temporarily dominates over the shield. In other words, it can be precarious temporary situation when means for cracking encryption developed further than methods of encryption.

Not having even simple substitution cyphers is a bit of a stretch...

@Gene Ok, maybe there are substitution cyphers, but people are already very good at cracking them.

Cryptography that existed is easy to crack for MODERN cryptologists... but the ability for a civilization to think of better ways to encrypt things is directly proportional to their creativity in cracking them.  So no, it was actually very rare, even 2000 years ago for an encoded message to be cracked by professionals from a rival faction.

@KarmaPeasant "people are already very good at cracking" - that means advanced cryptography. Or at least for some value of "advanced"...

@Nosajimiki
In the long run that is true, but there can be period when the sword temporarily dominates over the shield. In other words, it can be precarious temporary situation when means for cracking encryption developed further than methods of encryption.

@KarmaPeasant Or you could simply say that there is not Cryptography at play.  If the goal of your answer is that the messages are vague by design, then it suggests a civilization with very little concept of more advanced ways of hiding the meaning of a message.

@Nosajimiki It would be very strange if there was complete absence of even elementary substitution cyphers. It would suggest that this civilization is made out of beings that are intellectually inferior to real life humans. But if this is the case, then such beings would not be able to build a civilization.

@KarmaPeasant or there’s a religious text that says something akin to “speak always with a clear voice; let no shadow hide your thoughts” and suddenly everyone thinks cryptography is sinful. Single lines of religious text taken out of context have caused many oddities of our civilizations.

@SRM When it comes to money or power nobody really cares about religion. If it is profitable to use cryptography, then people will use it, no matter what religion says about its use.

@KarmaPeasant I’m not going to put together a list for you today, but in past answers, I’ve dug up several examples of tech being rejected for religious grounds, overriding economics. Easy to find on the small scale (Amish), but multiple large-scales exist in history.

@SRM Then it will mean that enemies of said country will have an advantage over it in said respect. Rejection of money/power/technology for religious reasons puts your in disadvantaged position compared to your less principled competitors/enemies. True both on personal and national scale.

@KarmaPeasant You can be disadvantaged in one area and advantaged in another.  Take the Byzantine Empire for example.  The vast majority of its population refused to fight in wars for hundreds of years because they saw killing, even in war, as a mortal sin. Yet, they were a very united and productive empire because of thier strong religious beliefs; so, even with an exceptionally small army of people willing to go to war for the number of people they had, thier soldiers were so well funded that they were the best trained and equipped army in the world at the time which made them successful.

@KarmaPeasant Yes. And wars have been lost because of that willful disadvantage. Just because you believe you wouldn’t do it doesn’t mean it isn’t somewhat common in human history. Religion trumps most other operating factors for decision making in large parts of our history and present.

The first Glyph is always a sentence structure which may include additional glyphs to add meaning.
Once upon a time, the mages of yore, were commissioned by a wise, though be it prudish king to devise a means of communicating easily between ships.  But much to the kings dismay, the sailors who were given this system had a habit of talking like... well sailors.  Their messages were often lude and quite offensive to the king.  So he commanded the mages to fix the system so that sailors could only speak about facts relevant maritime traffic and activities.  So the mages create a new system whereby sailors had to communicate via pre-scripted sentences with only a limited range of variables.
So, you could start a message with a glyph that defines your sentence structure like "<number> <type> ships approaching from <direction>."  This prevents most ways for a mischievous captain to order his few available glyphs into a double entendre or complex homonym or starting a conversation that is off topic.  Then you tap the glyphs for "3", "Enemy", "West".  So, by activating just 4 glyphs, you can communicate a complex but otherwise common sort of message.  Some messages might even only need one glyph like "Leaving now."  While the sailors did not like that they could no longer pass thier time calling eachother racist slurs, they did appreciate how much easier it now was to quickly communicate a message in an emergency.
This way, you could have 90 glyphs for sentences, and 10 glyphs reserved for variable options and be able to communicate a very wide and detailed range of things as long as what you are talking about is maritime related.
For an example of this kind of system actually working in the real world, I suggest playing Among Us with the parental controls on.  These predefined sentence structures make it virtually impossible to speak abusively or ask inappropriate questions while still giving players all of the sentence structures and variables they need to specifically talk about what they need to discuss in the game. Just replace the idea of text dropdown menus with glyphs.
Other reasons to justify a glyph system:
Speed: Nobody wants to have to type out a whole distress call during an emergency.  Even if an alphabetical system might be more versatile, saying the maximum amount with a minimum input means a ship can put out a whole distress message in just a few glyphs giving the messenger more time to get to the lifeboats or join the fight against the pirates that just boarded them.
Common Language: Because Glyphs are not alphabetical, it means that people who natively speak two different languages will be able to communicate by Glyph without needing a translator because  means the same thing regardless of if you natively speak Jotun, Dwarvish, Ghukliak, or whatnot.  While some other answers say you can arbitrarily assign an alphabet to the glyphs, that does nothing to ensure that the person you are hailing will understand you when you do.
Encoding: It also turns out that this is a good way to encode a message.  Since something as simple as  can mean "A category 2 storm is coming tomorrow". Since there is no underlying phonetic structure to decode, you either know what this means or you don't.  You can also make word glyphs mean different things based on what sentence glyph they are used with; so, even though  looks like a similar sentence, it could mean "I have silk to trade for gold". Where the meaning of  can be either "Category 2" or "Silk" and  could mean either "tomorrow" or "gold"... it all just depends on the context.  This means that you may actually be able to say thousands of words, even though you mostly use the same few glyphs over and over.

"A category 2 storm is coming tomorrow" and "A category 3 storm is coming tomorrow" is enough to reinvent Morse Code

And if we are concerned about speed, variables of some kind of complex sentence could be abused to fit more informationaly dense arbitrary messages. Especially if we can send entire list of sentences.

@KarmaPeasant Morris code was not invented until 1838.  Since this is a Pathfinder (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinder_Roleplaying_Game) setting, any discovery post Medieval would be anachronistic.  Yes, we know what Morris code is, but idea of binary data encoding simply did not exist back then.

@Nosajimiki The Baconian cypher is binary and was invented by Sir Francis Bacon during the Reign of Queen Elizabeth, on the tale end of the "vaguely medieval" timeframe Pathfinder and D&D use

@Nosajimiki It was not invented because there was no need for such invention before. In the proposed world people already got (basically) a magical telegraph, necessitating need for something akin Morse Code in order to send arbitrary messages.

@NoName But Bacon’s discovery of scientific method is often considered the line out of that time. I don’t think you can use something from someone who is the epitome of “I will usher the world into a new era”. :-)

What are the glyphs you've used in this answer?

@Josh just some random alchemical symbols.

Shipping is a magic word here
If you haven't been around shipping much you might have missed that this has been a solved problem for a couple of hundred years and there's a reference book for you to work from.

A Code of Signals for the use of vessels employed in the Merchant Service -  Frederick Marryat

First published in 1817, there's a later version which might also be useful to you

A Code of Signals for the Use of Vessels Employed in the Merchant Service Including a Cypher for Secret Correspondence

Some of the signals are still in use in simpler form and it's normal to have a crib sheet to hand.

Addendum: Since this is a pdf link it may expire, but it's the full current set of flag codes

Yes I used this document as inspiration to come up with my initial word list.

@WhatEvil, here's the rest of it if you really want full communications https://www.marinewaypoints.com/learn/flags/flagsignals.pdf given you're running a game it might be worth using some as easter eggs and see who found out about the full set. It's only 157 pages, though not all of it useful to you.

@Separatrix I have no idea what I'll use it for but thanks for that, I know it'll be handy one of these days.

Unfortunately we know you are not in fact up against a technical limit because something similar exists in the modern world; I give you the International Code of Signals, a set of symbols, usually in the form of flags, that can be used for communicating visually between ships at sea. These symbols can be used to communicate in individual numbers and letters as well as having more complex meanings, both singularly and in combination. There is no exhaustive list of possible combination signals since there are more than 40! (8.16x1047) options when you include multiple substitution flags, and that only includes the full strings, not the shorter combinations. Your current 15 glyphs gives you 1.3x1012 full strings.
That math gives us a clue to meaningfully limiting yourself though, to that end you need a much shorter list of basic glyphs; five individual symbols, letters, gives you just 120 total 5 glyph combinations, or words, in your library of complex codes (it does yield about 325 total permutations, of length 1-5, which may be more than you want but as 4 symbols gets you only 62 total permutations I think you need 5). Then you're into something like Toki Pona territory. Having worked on codes for games and books in the past it always amazes me how fast I run out of space within a limited set like that.
Unfortunately "crypticness", and thus what you need in a specific word list, is a matter of you and how your table of players respond. The lesson I learned from running the same dungeon as a player with two different groups was that when it comes to puzzles, not only YMMV but sometimes things that are obvious to one group are completely opaque to another.
Per my comment when I first saw this question I would also, if this was my creation, include several complex and unique glyphs, that can't appear in combinations in addition to the basic symbols. This gives you the option for something like "Oh no-one knows what that means, we think the Pharaohs of the Old Kingdom once used it for Nubia, the captain and I use it when we want to talk about the Swedes."

I think on "crypticness", it's a bit easier than it might be because I'll be interacting with the players and able to adapt - i.e. first I'll give them the symbols, then introduce letter substitution, then introduce cryptography, codebooks etc. depending on how they get on with the "previous" level.

@WhatEvil Yup and that's just the sort of insight I don't have to be able to give you an answer around the specific word list.

Frame challenge:
Do the messages have any additional information associated with them? Can you recognise the sender? The transmission frequency? The time of sending?
If you are concerned with eavesdroppers, you keep the message as short as possible, and with maximum entropy. You could identify the sender by the time of sending (12:17pm) for your sabotage team, and a set of simple codes for the likely outcomes...
1: target A destroyed
2: target B destroyed
3: both targets destroyed
4: neither target destroyed
You can have a large codebook and an alphabetic support for longer messages if things go way off track. But if being found with a codebook is bad, you may want to keep things very simple for the cryptic messages so you can keep them in your head, and just go plaintext if you are stuck and need pulling out.

Silly suggestion:
Your magical crystals don't talk to each other, they talk to one or more central hubs which relay the message to the correct end crystal.
The magic crystal system was originally programmed with the thousand word vocabulary of Basic English, a relatively well known simplification of English which can be used to explain even complex general or technical concepts.
The magic crystals are durable and reliable.  The hubs, less so.
Each hub has lost a subset of the available words.  Depending on what hub your message goes through, it will be mangled in different (though predictable) ways.
Ya want cryptic, this will give you cryptic.
Or a single central hub, where each word gets mapped to one of five possible meanings.
(Source, in part: trying to explain Round Robin DNS at work today (you get a (randomly or partly randomly selected from a short list) IP address when looking up a domain name.)

Yep! Nice idea. I suppose this could work really well if the system was originally created by some extinct civilization, or given as a gift by some gods who are no longer around or something like that.

You may enjoy taking inspiration from the messaging system from Elden Ring and other Soulsborne videogames. They consist of a premade message with replaceable blanks in it, similar to Mad Libs. This makes cryptic but relevant messages possible throughout the game.
Wiki of all possible messages: https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Messages
Good example of messages in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7umnYAVD-Y8

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answering my own question here:
I've had some more thoughts, and I think in terms of being able to use a messaging system like this whilst also keeping it cryptic there are a few ideas:
The messages are of limited length, and can only be sent a limited number of times per day, or once every time period (10 minutes, hour, etc. - which could also depend on distance e.g. the further away, the longer) before the device has to "recharge". Alternatively, maybe each device can send a limited number of messages before it has to be replaced or has to go back to the maker or some other special depot or person (e.g. "a 9th level wizard") for a recharge of magical energy, or something like that.
This somewhat gets around the "Well you can just assign letters/numbers to the glyphs and then spell out any arbitrary message" because of the more limited nature.
You would still be able to spell things out, or have e.g. some larger combinatorial dictionary whereby each combination of signals is assigned to a different word, but even then you'd be more limited than just having a plaintext messaging system. Even if you had only 16 glyphs then you could encode unique pairs of glyphs to a total of 2^16 (=65,536) arbitrary words or phrases... but if you're limited to say 12 total glyphs sent per message, then you're still limited to quite short messages, plus you have to carry around a huge dictionary/codebook with you.
Of course even with the above limits, you could carry multiple messaging devices around with you. There's no real limitation if you can carry around 100 of the devices.
So ultimately, in summary, in order to (somewhat) achieve the limited/cryptic nature of the messaging system, you probably need to have:

A limited number of unique glyphs.
A limited number of glyphs per message.
A limited number of messages - either per time period (3 messages per day/week etc.) or some kind of cost per message or other justification to disincentivise sending lots of messages in sequence.

The limitation to the number of messages must also take into account the possibility of multiple devices being available - so it may be necessary to make the devices or the resources to make them/recharge them be scarce or otherwise costly.
All of these things can easily be justified if building your own world, in different ways, such as:

The limited number of unique glyphs are just an inherent limitation of the magic. Maybe the more glyphs there are, the more costly the devices are to make or operate, or maybe the user has to psychically interact with the device in order to compose the message, and the more glyphs there are, the harder it gets to control it.
Ditto the limited number of glyphs per message. Maybe there are other limitations like the size of the device. This kind of thing may leave it open to organisations with more resources being able to have more advanced messaging systems by spending more money to create very large devices which are stationed at their headquarters which can send and receive, say, 50 glyphs per message.

I think ultimately if you have a world where magic is available/used for things like this, then it's very easy and perfectly acceptable to handwave away objections by saying things like "That's just a limitation of the magic" or "The wizards who created the devices have been trying to figure out how to expand the functionality of the devices but haven't been able to find the right runes/reagents" etc.
Another fun idea might be that there's some societal or organisational reason why the devices aren't more capable. Maybe the wizards did originally make the devices more capable but they were sued in a lawsuit from the Messengers' Guild because it was adversely affecting their business.
